# C++ dynamic binding with overloading

Tags: c++, binding, overloading

Suppose:

```
struct A {
    virtual int foo(const A& a) const { return 1; }
};

struct B : A {
    virtual int foo(const A& a) const { return 2; }
    virtual int foo(const B& b) const { return 3; }
};

void testOverloadingBinding(const A& a,const B& b) {
    cout << a.foo(b);
}

int main() {
    testOverloadingBinding(B(),B());
}
```

It prints 2. I would assume it prints 3 since `this` binding is dynamic, and as far as I know overloading has static binding.
Can anyone please explain how the compiler decides which function to invoke here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
virtual int foo(const B& b) const;
```

is not an override for this:

```
virtual int foo(const A& a) const;
```

Therefore it can never be called via a reference to an `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual int foo(const B& b) const;
```

doesn't override anything, so compiler chooses first function. But, probably in future, we will have a dynamic type resolution, and in this case compiler will choose second function.
For more info, see http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/multimethods.pdf

Comment: What makes you think that C++ will support double dispatch in the future?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth 1 - it will simplify pattern visitor. 2 - overhead will be only in case of defining type like virtual(see proposal). 3 - it will simplify usage of multimethods. 4 - it is initiative from Bjarne Stroustrup :)

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no overload available to resolve to. The object you are calling `foo` on is of type `A` and in `A` only one function `foo(const A&)` exists. The dynamic dispatching yields the function in the base class. In C++ a member function is identified by its name and its arguments. Adding an overload in a base that does not exist in the parent will not enable dynamic dispatch onto it.